# Multiplying strings in a list by numbers from another list, element by element

Tags: python, list

I have two lists, `['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']` and `[1, 2, 3, 4]`. Both lists will always have the same number of items. I need to multiply each string by its number, so the final product I am looking for is:

```
['A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D']
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Repeat each item in a list a number of times specified in another list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33382474/repeat-each-item-in-a-list-a-number-of-times-specified-in-another-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nested list comprehension works too:

```
>>> l1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'] 
>>> l2 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> [c for c, i in zip(l1, l2) for _ in range(i)]
['A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D']
```

In above [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) returns `(char, count)` tuples:

```
>>> t = list(zip(l1, l2))
>>> t
[('A', 1), ('B', 2), ('C', 3), ('D', 4)]
```

Then for every tuple the second `for` loop is executed `count` times to add the character to the result:

```
>>> [char for char, count in t for _ in range(count)]
['A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D']
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `itertools.repeat` for a nice, efficient implementation:

```
>>> letters = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
>>> numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> import itertools
>>> result = []
>>> for letter, number in zip(letters, numbers):
...     result.extend(itertools.repeat(letter, number))
...
>>> result
['A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D']
>>>
```

I also think it is quite readable.

Answer (score 0):

The code is pretty straight forward, see inline comments

```
l1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'] 
l2 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
res = []
for i, x in enumerate(l1): # by enumerating you get both the item and its index
    res += x * l2[i] # add the next item to the result list
print res
```

**OUTPUT**

```
['A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D']
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `zip()` to do it like this way:

```
a = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
b = [1, 2, 3, 4]

final = []
for k,v in zip(a,b):
    final += [k for _ in range(v)]

print(final)
```

Output:

```
>>> ['A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D']
```

Or you can do it, too, using `zip()` and `list comprehension`:

```
a = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
b = [1, 2, 3, 4]
final = [k for k,v in zip(a,b) for _ in range(v)]
print(final)
```

Output:

```
>>> ['A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use NumPy and then convert the NumPy array to a list:

```
letters = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
times = [1, 2, 3, 4]
np.repeat(letters, times).tolist()

#output

['A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D']
```