# How to multiply a list of strings by a list of integers?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to multiply `a * b`:

```
a = ['a', 'e', 'y']    
b = [3, 2, 1]
```

and get:

```
c = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'e', 'e', 'y']
```

Comment: @olaf It is not a mathematics question.  An operation such as `['foo']*3` is defined in Python.

Comment: @Olaf A string times a number is a perfectly valid and defined operation in Python. Ex: `'a' * 3` is `'aaa'` in this case.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser: And it is even given in the tutorial. I know. But that does not make the operqation a [multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication). **That** term is well defined. And for the other thing, OP should learn the language and show his code plus what the problem is.

Comment: This has probably been asked before, please read the language's docs at https://docs.python.org and consider using a simple "for i in range" loop where you can c += [a[i]] * b[i] in each iteration.

Comment: A better duplicate target: [Repeat each item in a list a number of times specified in another list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33382474/7851470).

Answer (score 3):

That can be done with [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum), [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) like:

#### Code:

```
c = sum([[s] * n for s, n in zip(a, b)], [])
```

#### Test Code:

```
a = ['a', 'e', 'y']
b = [3, 2, 1]

c = sum([[s] * n for s, n in zip(a, b)], [])
print(c)
```

#### Result:

```
['a', 'a', 'a', 'e', 'e', 'y']
```

Answer (score 2):

[`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) is your friend here:

```
a = ['a', 'e', 'y']

b = [3, 2, 1]

c = []
for x, y in zip(a, b):
    c.extend([x] * y)

print(c)
# ['a', 'a', 'a', 'e', 'e', 'y']
```

Or with [`itertools.chain.from_iterable()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
from itertools import chain

c = list(chain.from_iterable([x] * y for x, y in zip(a, b)))

print(c)
# ['a', 'a', 'a', 'e', 'e', 'y']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
a = ['a', 'e', 'y']    
b = [3, 2, 1]
new_list = [i for b in [[c]*d for c, d in zip(a, b)] for i in b]
```

Output:

```
['a', 'a', 'a', 'e', 'e', 'y']
```

Answer (score 1):

The most basic loop approach would be this, in my opinion:

```
a = ['a', 'e', 'y']
b = [3, 2, 1]
c = []

for i in range(len(a)):
    c.extend(list(a[i]*b[i]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Fancy one liner:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> a = ['a', 'e', 'y']
>>> b = [3, 2, 1]
>>> c = list(chain(*[x*y for x,y in zip(a,b)]))
>>> c
['a', 'a', 'a', 'e', 'e', 'y']
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need to import any modules, as I said in the comments, please consider reading the Python docs.

```
a = ['a', 'e', 'y']    
b = [3, 2, 1]
c = []

for i in range(len(a)):
    c += [a[i]] * b[i]

print(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Through **collections.Counter** you can do this:-

**Try this:-**

```
from collections import Counter
a = ['a', 'e', 'y']    
b = [3, 2, 1]
d = {x:y for x,y in zip(a,b)}
c = Counter(d)
print(list(c.elements())) #your output
```