# How to separate strings in a list, multiplied by a number

Tags: python, string, list, separator

I need to take a list, multiply every item by 4 and separate them by coma.

My code is:

```py
conc = ['0.05 ml : 25 ml', '0.05 ml : 37.5 ml', '0.05 ml : 50 ml', '0.05 ml : 62.5 ml', '0.05 ml : 75 ml']
new_conc = [", ".join(i*4) for i in conc]
print(new_conc)
```

But when I run it, I get every SYMBOL separated by come. What I need is multiplied number of shown EXPRESSIONS separated by coma.

So the output should be:

`['0.05 ml : 25 ml', '0.05 ml : 25 ml', '0.05 ml : 25 ml', '0.05 ml : 25 ml', '0.05 ml : 37.5 ml', '0.05 ml : 37.5 ml', '0.05 ml : 37.5 ml', '0.05 ml : 37.5 ml', '0.05 ml : 50 ml', '0.05 ml : 50 ml', '0.05 ml : 50 ml', '0.05 ml : 50 ml', '0.05 ml : 62.5 ml', '0.05 ml : 62.5 ml', '0.05 ml : 62.5 ml', '0.05 ml : 62.5 ml', '0.05 ml : 75 ml', '0.05 ml : 75 ml', '0.05 ml : 75 ml', '0.05 ml : 75 ml']`

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69737765/how-to-separate-strings-multiplied-by-integer-in-python) answered question, but as I already mentioned, I get separate **symbols**, separated by coma.

Comment: Your list contains strings, not numbers. When you use `*` on a string, it duplicates it that many times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a simple `for` loop.

```
new_conc = []
for item in conc:
    new_conc.extend([item] * 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try double for-loop:

```py
conc = ['0.05 ml : 25 ml', '0.05 ml : 37.5 ml', '0.05 ml : 50 ml', '0.05 ml : 62.5 ml', '0.05 ml : 75 ml']

out = []
for item in conc:
    for _ in range(4):
        out.append(item)
print(out)
```

---

Or one-liner:

```
out = [item for item in conc for _ in range(4)]
```

---

Or (if order as you stated in your output is not important):

```
out = conc * 4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly multiply a string, you need to "separate" the numeric part from the non-numeric one, then you can perform your multiplication, and finally rejoin the numeric and the string parts.

```py
conc = ['0.05 ml : 25 ml', '0.05 ml : 37.5 ml', '0.05 ml : 50 ml', '0.05 ml : 62.5 ml', '0.05 ml : 75 ml']

multiplied_conc = [': '.join([f"{float(p.split()[0])*4} {p.split()[1]}" for p in c.split(' : ')]) for c in conc]

print(multiplied_conc)
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, when I despaired of finding an answer and posted this question, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48837245/how-to-multiply-a-list-of-strings-by-a-list-of-integers) answered question. :)

So the solution to my problem can be:

```
b = [4, 4, 4, 4]
c = sum([[s] * n for s, n in zip(conc, b)], [])
print(c)
```

But, if you, guys, know better solution, I will be happy to hear it!

Comment: You don't need the `b` list if it's always 4. Just use `[s] * 4`

Comment: Thank you! I am pretty new to Python and although I spend a lot of time studying it, I still sometimes get confused about simple things :) Thank you!