# How do I create a deck of cards in terms of the number in a file in python?

Tags: python

Here is the file:

```
Admiral,30,1
General,25,1
Colonel,20,2
Major,15,2
Captain,10,2
Lieutenant,7,2
Sergeant,5,4
Corporal,3,6
Private,1,10
```

I need to display the deck (in list form) and output how many cards there are. The last number in the file represents how many cards there are. So there is 1 Admiral card in the deck, 2 Colonel, 10 Private, etc.

Below is my code so far:

```
numFile = open("ranks.dat", "r")

#list fields
rankList = []
skillList = []
numberList = []

while True:
    text = numFile.readline()
    text = text.rstrip("\n")
    if text=="":
        break
    info = text.split(",")
    rankList.append(info[0])
    skillList.append(int(info[1]))
    numberList.append(int(info[2]))


numFile.close

print("Rank\t\tSkill\t\tNumber")
print(45*"=")
for i in range(len(rankList)):
    print("%-10s\t%3i\t\t%3i" %(rankList[i], skillList[i], numberList[i]))
```

How do I add the deck of cards list?

How do I add the deck of cards in a list? This is how the list is supposed to look:

```
========================================
        Level 3 Build Deck
========================================
['Admiral', 'General', 'Colonel', 'Colonel', 'Major', 'Major', 'Captain', 'Captain', 'Lieutenant', 'Lieutenant', 'Sergeant', 'Sergeant', 'Sergeant', 'Sergeant', 'Corporal', 'Corporal', 'Corporal', 'Corporal', 'Corporal', 'Corporal', 'Private', 'Private', 'Private', 'Private', 'Private', 'Private', 'Private', 'Private', 'Private', 'Private']
```

Comment: And what's the *problem* with that code?

Comment: @jonrsharpe there is no problem with that code, I need to add the deck of cards lists from the file, but I am not sure how to do that

Comment: So could you rephrase your question -- or open a new one -- to do with reading from a file in Python. Ideally, give us an example of the file you want to read.

Comment: @mrblewog yea sure I can do that, how do I give you an example of the file you want to read -- is there any way to attach it? I put the content of the file at the top of the file, is that enough?

Comment: It seems your code works okay in displaying the deck of cards from your file example.  Are you only missing showing the total number of cards? The number of cards is just `sum([int(x) for x in numberList])`

Comment: Yeah, that's fine. So with the content `Admiral,30,1` etc in a file called `ranks.dat` and a python file called `main.py` with your Python code, I can read the the file and print out some rows... is that what you expect?

Comment: @mrblewog I just added how I want the output to look, is that helpful?

Comment: Very much, yes. You already know about the range(n) function and about appending to lists, so you have the building blocks....

Comment: @mrblewog so what should my next step be?

Answer (score 0):

**Refactoring Posted Software**

The following simplifies posted code and creates same output

> Note: rename file ranks.txt (i.e. txt file normally end with txt
>   suffix).

```
with open("ranks.txt", "r") as f:
  rankList, skillList, numberList = zip(*[x.rstrip().split(',') for x in f])

skillList = [int(x) for x in skillList]
numberList = [int(x) for x in numberList]

print("Rank\t\tSkill\t\tNumber")
print(45*"=")
for i in range(len(rankList)):
    print("%-10s\t%3i\t\t%3i" %(rankList[i], skillList[i], numberList[i]))
```

**To Build Deck List**

[Inspired by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33382474/repeat-each-item-in-a-list-a-number-of-times-specified-in-another-list)

Build Deck

```
deck = [rank for rank, number in zip(rankList, numberList) for i in range(number)]
print(deck)
```

Or equivalently using for loops

```
deck = []
for i in range(len(rankList)):
  rank = rankList[i]
  number = numberList[i]
  for repeat in range(number):
    deck.append(rank)
```

**Output**

```
['Admiral', 'General', 'Colonel', 'Colonel', 'Major', 'Major', 'Captain', 'Captain', 'Lieutenant', 'Lieutenan
t', 'Sergeant', 'Sergeant', 'Sergeant', 'Sergeant', 'Corporal', 'Corporal', 'Corporal', 'Corporal', 'Corporal
', 'Corporal', 'Private', 'Private', 'Private', 'Private', 'Private', 'Private', 'Private', 'Private', 'Priva
te', 'Private']
```

**Explanation**

Build Deck List Comprehension

```
deck = [rank for rank, number in zip(rankList, numberList) for repeat in range(number)]
```

Create sequence of pairs of rank and number of that rank

```
zip(rankList, numberList)
```

Iterate over these pairs

```
 for rank, number zip(rankList, numberList)
```

Repeat rank based upon the `number` in each pair

```
 [rank for rank, number in zip(rankList, numberList) for repeat in range(number)]
```

**Complete Software**

```
numFile = open("ranks.dat", "r")

#list fields
rankList = []
skillList = []
numberList = []

while True:
    text = numFile.readline()
    text = text.rstrip("\n")
    if text=="":
        break
    info = text.split(",")
    rankList.append(info[0])
    skillList.append(int(info[1]))
    numberList.append(int(info[2]))

numFile.close

print("Rank\t\tSkill\t\tNumber")
print(45*"=")
for i in range(len(rankList)):
    print("%-10s\t%3i\t\t%3i" %(rankList[i], skillList[i], numberList[i]))

deck = []
for i in range(len(rankList)):
  rank = rankList[i]
  number = numberList[i]
  for repeat in range(number):
    deck.append(rank)

print(deck)
```

Comment: @DarryIG is there anyway not to use the iterate? and zip? I have never learned that

Comment: @unknownmac--sure--I'll expand to do it with a normal for loop.

Comment: @unknownmac--added version using for loops.  Does it make sense?

Comment: @DarryIG Thanks a lot! Now when I run it, its not showing anything tho. Perhaps I am making a mistake?

Comment: @DarryIG numFile = open("ranks.dat", "r") #list fields rankList = [] skillList = [] numberList = [] deck = [] while True: text = numFile.readline() text = text.rstrip("\n") if text=="": break info = text.split(",") for i in range(len(rankList)): rank = rankList[i] number = numberList[i] for repeat in range(number): deck.append(rank) numFile.close

Comment: @unknownmac--I added the complete software at the end which is just an addition to your original software.

Comment: @DarryIG Thanks a lot!